# using an empty space(tried div float) on my website that's using div container

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a webpage that's using div container and inside that container it's divided into 8 and 4. but next to that 8(left side) there's an empty space(Because I'm using container) and I want to use that empty space. I've tried div float left but this pushes everything to the right little bit which pushes 4(right side) away. Here's my code

```
<div class="container">
   <div>
       <div class="row placeholders">
            <div class="col-sm-8">

            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">

            </div>
       </div>    
 </div>
```

for example,, on stackoverflow, there's space on very left side but on youtube https://www.youtube.com/ there's no space on very left side. I'm trying to make it like youtube

Comment: Is [`.container-fluid`](https://getbootstrap.com/css/#overview-container) what you want?

Comment: but if I use that won't my             <div class="col-sm-8">
and             <div class="col-sm-4">
stay still?

Comment: I'm honestly stumped on this problem. The only fix that I can think of is to add the extra content with col-sm-2 and have col-sm-8 and col-sm-4 reduced to col-sm-7 and col-sm-3.

Comment: @kimkimm I think you might need to provide more detail in what you're trying to achieve. Are you trying to achieve _exactly_ how youtube behaves when you resize the window?

Comment: @ordonezalex not resizing I simply want to write some stuff on the next to col-sm-8

Comment: @HTMLNoob I think that's the way to go as well, I will try it and let you know

Comment: I think I understand now. Why not use another `.col`? I think three `.col`s would be the simplest solution.

Comment: cuz I like the way mine displays right now, also if I use another col that means there will  be an empty space on the left side again. <just the size of what's already being displayed is being decreased>

Comment: @HTMLNoob hey  did you get the point by the way?

Comment: No didnt it got down voted to death

Comment: @HTMLNoob you should just post https://django-haystack.readthedocs.org/en/v2.4.0/ and put read this, the bounty expires tmrw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the answer that I provided in the comments.

```
<div class="container">
    <div>
        <div class="row placeholders">
            <div class="col-sm-2">
                <p>Lorem ipsum sit amet</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-7">
                <p>Lorem ipsum sit amet</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <p>Lorem ipsum sit amet</p>
            </div>
        </div>
```

[Working Example](http://codepen.io/HTMLNoob/pen/gPRaKv)

Comment: I think I should use container-fluid for this, do you know how I should approach if i were to usee container fluid instead

Comment: Ok here is the codepen                                                                                http://codepen.io/HTMLNoob/pen/gPRaKv

Comment: oh ok, I didnt know that. Thank you GitaarLAB. :)

Comment: @HTMLNoob, thanks for the codepen...I'm trying it to adopt with mycode right now

Comment: hey man thank you so much it works, in your opinion, what is the size of left bar that contains best of youtube on youtube? https://www.youtube.com/

Comment: I cant say the best of youtube area is not visible in my browser.

Comment: ok. I have one last question. I'm done after this. Can you check it out? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34715897/using-multiple-colors-of-background-to-the-web

Answer (score 1):

Use one more .col-* and set padding left and padding right to 0.

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="row placeholders">
       <div class="col-sm-2" style="padding-left:0;padding-right:0;">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
        </div>
       <div class="col-sm-4">
       </div>
  </div>
```

You can do same with container space. Either you can use `.container-fluid`or using `container`reset `margin-left` and `margin-right` property.

Comment: would it better to use container-fluid?I\m looking into this, and seems like it will do the job?but I don't have any experience with container-fluid??how do I solve this problem with container fluid because it seems like a lot of people use fluid

Comment: Your answer is an almost complete copy to the answer that I provided in the comments.

Comment: @kim kimm  `.container ` has fixed width for each screen size i.e (xs,sm,md,lg) in bootstrap & `container-fluid`  expands according to the available width of the screen, so its width changes every time the viewport width changes. So it can be used in your case.


@ HTMLNoob I didn't see your answer while answering mine as I was in mobile device ;)

Comment: np nothing personal there amarmishra :)