# using multiple colors of background to the web

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Sorry if the title is little bit misleading. 
What I'm trying to do is to cover my background of index page with really light grey except for the section that displays my contents.

```
<div class="col-sm-1">
</div>
<div class="col-sm-8">
</div>
<div class="col-sm-3">
</div>
```

I want col-sm-8 to be the only white, and rest to be all grey. 
I can make col-sm-8 grey using css, but how do I do the opposite?

Comment: You can just use the grey color for `col-sm-1` and `col-sm-3` right? :)

Comment: Yeah the answer provided by Manoj Kumar should work efficiently.

Comment: html/css/js basically frontend community is so much nicer than backend and db community :o

Comment: I believe its just that there is alot more front-end developers than back-end developers. (I'm not trying to offend any back-end developers.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
[class*="col-"] {
    background : grey;
}

.col-sm-8{
  background: white;
}
```

well, what  `[class*="col-"]` selector do is that it will give grey background to the values of class attributes begin with col-

You can style individual classes by writing its full class name.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want like following.

You can do opposite this way.

```css
div:not(.col-sm-8){
 background-color:grey; 
}
```

```html
<div class="col-sm-1">test1
</div>
<div class="col-sm-8">test8
</div>
<div class="col-sm-3">test3
</div>
```

Or Use following using class selector.

```css
[class*="col-sm-"]:not(.col-sm-8){
 background-color:grey; 
}
```

```html
<div class="col-sm-1">test1
</div>
<div class="col-sm-8">test8
</div>
<div class="col-sm-3">test3
</div>
```

**[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lqh7a5vt/1/)**

Read more about **[:not](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/n/not/)** here.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of bootstrap class put your own style(inline-css)

```html
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container bg-info">

container <br/>container <br/>
 <div class="col-sm-1 bg-warning">
k
</div>
<div class="col-sm-8 bg-success">
k
</div>
<div class="col-sm-3 bg-warning">k
</div>

container <br/>container <br/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use selector like `[class*="col-"]:not(.col-sm-8)`

```css
[class*="col-"]:not(.col-sm-8){
 background-color:grey; 
}
```

```html
<div class="col-sm-1">1
</div>
<div class="col-sm-8">2
</div>
<div class="col-sm-3">3
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Either using the inline designing you can use

```
<div style="color:#0000FF"> //use the div name
```

or else you can use css to design it

```
[class*="col-"] {
    background : grey;
}

.col-sm-8{
  background: white;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also style elements individually.

```
.col-sm-1{
width:100%;
height:100px;
background:grey;
}
.col-sm-8{
width:100%;
height:100px;
background:white;

}
.col-sm-3{
  width:100%;
  height:100px;
 background:grey;
}
```

But if your using entirely bootstrap in your project you have to avoid giving styles to bootstrap builtin classes.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the answer provided by Jinu Kurian sounds like the answer that you want but in case the answer is that you want everything light grey and col-sm-8 with a background of white. This should work.

```css
.container {
  background-color: grey;/*Replace this with a hex color value of a light grey to your preferance*/
  }
.col-sm-8 {
    background-color: white;
  }
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

  <div class="container">
  <div class="col-sm-1">
    <p>Lorem ipsum sit amet</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-8">
    <p>Lorem ipsum sit amet</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-3">
    <p>Lorem ipsum sit amet</p>
  </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: kim kimm Though i have helped you with many different questions. Please dont try to be biased here. I honestly believe that many of the answers here are much better than mine. Moreover many of these guys know alot more than I do. For example: shijjin has a working example. Jinu Kurian has a working example. These two examples are much more flexible than mine.

Comment: which one would you say is better

Comment: they pretty much all work, not sure which one will give fastest time

Comment: you guys are number one in heart *wink

Comment: but seriously which one will give fastest time?

Comment: lol all of them are pretty much the same when it comes to the speed of putting the answer to use. You might as well do "eeny meeny miny mo"

Comment: @ketan i just say that these almost all are correct.not for accepting answers

Comment: @kimkimm i thing this is just simple css selectors.not affect speed much.

Comment: I did eeny miny mo for you and I ended at jinu Kurians answer

Comment: ok Heres a deal everybody just start liking everybody elses answer that way we all get points :)

Comment: by the way, do you know any good color match for background/content section? I found a good list, I thought maybe I share with you http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_colornames.asp

Comment: I'd say "steelblue" and #cccccc

Comment: white smoke and ghost white

Comment: by the way can you help me with moving button to the center///?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100344/discussion-between-htmlnoob-and-kim-kimm).

Comment: @kim kimm Need help?